# Ruby Script to Edit a RichText Editor

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm new to Watir. I have installed Watir 3.0.0. amd Ruby 1.9.3. I am writing scripts to automate a Web aplication. It has a forum in which a Rich Text Box is present to post comments. I cant find any properties like name and id for the Rich Text Box in the Script. How to automate it? I want to enter text in it and automate the Rich TextBox.

Please help me write my Watir Script.

```
<td>
  <select>
  <option value="Trebuchet MS,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
  Trebuchet
  <option value="arial,helvetica,sans-serif">
  Text - Arial
<td>
  <div class="space"/>
<td>
  <select>
    <option value="1">
      Text - 1 (8 pt)
    <option value="2">
      Text - 2 (10 pt)
<td>
  <div class="space"/>
<table border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
       <div title="Justify Left" class="button">
        <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" src="http://xxxxx.com/images/ed_align_left.gif" complete="complete"/>
      <td>
        <div title="Justify Center" class="button">
          <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" src="http://xxxxxxxx.com/images/ed_align_center.gif" complete="complete"/>
        <iframe class="iframe" src="http://xxxxxx.com/blank.html" style="width: 591px; height: 334px;">
          <html>
            <head>
             <title></title>
             <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
             <base href="http://xxxxxx.com/forum/"/>
             <style type="text/css">CSS Stylesheet</style>
           <body contentEditable="true">
             <font size="2"/>
```

This is how it looks. Here's a part of code that Im trying to test. ContentEditable=true represents the textbox. How to script a test to edit the textbox using Ruby... ??? Help!!!

Thanks for the info Chuck...Please Help!!!

Comment: Please provide link to the page, or a similar one, or relevant HTML.

Comment: I'm testing my Organization's website so i cant reveal the Rich TextBox site. But i can share an image of how it looks but there's no option here ... please guide...i havent found it anywhere else...

Comment: Why did you create another question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10995107/17469 Please edit this one instead of creating new questions.

Comment: it's nearly impossible for us to tell you how to script against a site we can't see unless you can provide us with samples of the html

Comment: I've edited the message to make an attempt at formatting your html, however it seems like some pretty strange stuff because a lot of close tags don't seem to be present where i would expect them to be.   For future reference don't use the grave accent to demark code unless it is inline `like this`  for blocks of code just indent 4 spaces and SO does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Is the rich text editor your own code or some third party library such as a Jquery  control?

The reason I ask is that if it is not your own code, there is not a lot of value to testing someone elses code, especially if it's something you are paying for.  You might be better off to just 'set' the contents of the editor to the text you need in order to test your application, and not spend a lot of energy testing someone elses code beyond making sure it has been properly configured (to enable/disable the desired functions)

Comment: Its written in Javascript. And there's no ID or name for the textbox. It appears within a table and has no attributes. I can't attach a screen shot as I'm new to this Forum.

Comment: This is how the html looks ..... and contenteditable is the one that appears in IE Development Toolbar

Comment: <html> <head> <title></title> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> <base href="http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/forum/"/> <style type="text/css">CSS Stylesheet</style> <body contentEditable="true"> <font size="2"/>

Comment: edit the original question to insert the html there where it can be properly formatted.  trying to read it in fragments in the comments doesn't work.

Comment: "And there's no ID or name for the textbox. It appears within a table and has no attributes."  sounds like you need to have a discussion with your developers on this concept called 'testability'.  of course there is also the question of why in the world would they take the time and effort to roll their own text editor control when there are so many existing ones already out there that could generally be easily reused.  https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+text+editor

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your edit control is entirely within a frame which is likely what is giving you fits.  You need to read about how to work with frames   Start [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames)